# Is it possible to use `class-validator` with antd `Form.useForm`()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, antd, class-validator

I have created a DTO object with `class-validator`:

```
export class CreateItemDto {
  @IsString()
  @Length(2, 63)
  readonly name: string;
}
```

Is it possible to use it in `Form.useForm()` in Ant Design or I have to create rules on my own as following?

```
const [form] = Form.useForm<CreateItemDto>();

return (
  <Form form={form}>
    <Form.Item
      label="Name"
      name="name"
      rules={[{
        required: true,
        message: t('Please enter correct name'),
        min: 2,
        max: 63,
      }]}
    >
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think antd supports validating forms with `class-validator` by default. You could try running the `class-validator` `validate` function manually and wiring it to form rules via a custom validator rule.

https://codesandbox.io/s/registration-antd-4-17-3-forked-5x92w?file=/index.js:0-1142

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input } from "antd";
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
import { CreateItemDto } from "./CreateItemDto";

const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="register"
    >
      <Form.Item
        name="name"
        label="Name"
        hasFeedback
        rules={[
          {
            validator: async (_, value) => {
              const dto = new CreateItemDto({
                name: value
              });

              let errors = await validate(dto, {
                skipMissingProperties: true
              });

              if (errors?.length > 0) {
                console.log(errors);
                return Promise.reject(new Error('Validation errors'));
              } else {
                return Promise.resolve();
              }
            }
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<RegistrationForm />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```
import {
  Length,
  IsString
} from 'class-validator';

export class CreateItemDto {
  @IsString()
  @Length(2, 4)
  name: string;

  constructor({ name }: { name: string}) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```